# I am trying to create a diamond shape in Java

Tags: java

I currently have this code which allows me to create the left half of the diamond shape. Is there any way to mirror it to complete the right half. Or a completely different way of creating this shape.

[image: What should be my diamond shape]

```
public class diamond {
    int size = 0; //sets a starting value for size
    static int length = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //creates half of our diamond shape :(
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int j = length - 1 - i;
            for (int k = length / 2; k < length; k++) { 
                if (k == i || k == j || k == length + 7 + i - j) 
                    System.out.print("X"); 
                else
                    System.out.print(" "); 
            } 
            System.out.println(""); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a diamond using Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309203/how-to-make-a-diamond-using-nested-for-loops)

Comment: Two remarks: variable `size` - as is - is unused. --- Class names in Java should always start with an uppercase letter (`public class diamont { ...` -> `public class Diamond { ...`)

Comment: For the image is the value of `size == 10` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative that takes a slightly different approach.

- Since certain widths or lines can't be specified exactly and always have a single middle line, this just prompts for a number.
- It calculates spacing and adjusts the field of asterisks within two loops. The first does the top and middle line. The second just does the bottom portion.

```
String symb = "*";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int max = 0;
while (max <= 1) {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive no > 1: ");
    max = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Width and height are " + (2*max -3)+"\n");
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(max - i) + symb);
    symb += "**";
}

for (int i = 2; i < max; i++) {
    System.out
            .println(" ".repeat(i) + symb.substring(2 * i));
}
```

When prompted for and provided an input of 5, this prints.

```
Enter a positive no > 1: 5
Width and height are 7

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

You can modify this to produce the type of diamond you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below code prints the diamond pattern as per your diagram. This program allows the user to input the no of rows for the diamond and also allows the user to select any shape you want to create your diamond with.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int n, i, j, space = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Symbol : ");
        char c = s.next().charAt(0);
        
        drawDiamond(n,c);
    }
    
    static void drawDiamond(int n, char c) { 
        int i, j, space, k = 0; 
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
            for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) { 
                System.out.print(" "); 
            } 
            while (k != (2 * i - 1)) { 
                if (k == 0 || k == 2 * i - 2) 
                    System.out.print(c); 
                else
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                k++; 
            } 
            k = 0;  
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
        n--;
        
        for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) { 
            for (j = 0; j <= n - i; j++) { 
                System.out.print(" "); 
            } 
            k = 0; 
            while (k != (2 * i - 1)) { 
                if (k == 0 || k == 2 * i - 2) 
                    System.out.print(c); 
                else
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                k++; 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Sample Output :

```
Enter the number of rows: 4                                                                                                                                
Enter Symbol : *                                                                                                                                           
   *                                                                                                                                                       
  * *                                                                                                                                                      
 *   *                                                                                                                                                     
*     *                                                                                                                                                    
 *   *                                                                                                                                                     
  * *                                                                                                                                                      
   *
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code draws a diamond like your picture but only works with odd numbers.

```
class Diamond{
    int size = 0;
    static int length = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int outerSpace = length / 2;  //number left to the first x
        int count = outerSpace;       //same number used to find the mid 
        int up = 0;                    //counter for the space between the xx

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i < count) {                             //this code gets used till you reach the middle 
                for (int j = 0; j < outerSpace; j++) {     //prints space left of x
                    System.out.print(" ");      
                }
                System.out.print("X");
                for (int k = 0; k < up; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");                  //prints space between the x
                }
                System.out.println("X");
                outerSpace--;
                up += 2;
            }else{                                       //code after middle
                for (int j = 0; j < outerSpace; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("X");
                for (int k = 0; k < up; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("X");
                outerSpace++;
                up -= 2;
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact same design, The input length has to be even number.

```
public class Main {
    private static int legnth = 10;
    private static int x = legnth /2;
    private static int y = x + 1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1; i <= legnth/2; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j <= legnth; j++) {
                if(j==x || j==y) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            x--;
            y++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        
        x+=2;
        y-=2;
        
        
        for(int i=1; i < legnth/2; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j < legnth; j++) {
                if(j==x || j==y) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            x++;
            y--;
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

output

```
    **    
   *  *   
  *    *  
 *      * 
*        *
 *      *
  *    * 
   *  *  
    **
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. It will work for any valid odd integer value given for `length`.

```
void createDiamond(int length) {
  int n = length / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++) {
      if ((i >= 0 && i <= n && (j == n - i || j == n + 1 + i))
          || (i > n && i < length && (j == i - n || j == length + n - i)))
        System.out.print("X");
      else
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
createDiamond(9);
```

```
    XX    
   X  X   
  X    X  
 X      X 
X        X
 X      X 
  X    X  
   X  X   
    XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution where you can create a string array for one fourth of the diamond and later manipulate that array to print it into diamond. It can take even or odd both to create a diamond like shape.

```
  static int length=9;
        static int n=length/2;
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
            String []arr = new String[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                String space="";
                 int j = n - i;
                 for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) { 
                     space=space+" ";
                  }
                  arr[i]=space+"X";                  
                }
```

// To print upper half of diamond

```
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                String upper= arr[i] + arr[n -1 -i].substring(0,arr[n-1-i].length()-2) 
                                    + arr[n -1 -i].substring(1,arr[n -1 -i].length());
                System.out.println(upper);
            }
```

//      To print middle of the diamond

```
System.out.println("X" + arr[0].substring(0,arr[0].length()-1) 
                   +arr[0].substring(0,arr[0].length()-1) + "X");
```

//     To print down half of the diamond

```
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                String down= arr[n -1 -i]+arr[i].substring(0,arr[i].length()-2)
                        +arr[i].substring(1,arr[i].length());
                System.out.println(down);
            }
        }
```