# Java Diamond of Stars help explanation please

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi I’m a newbie in Java and I’m trying to understand the logic behind the for loops of diamond of stars Not just copy and paste it. If there is anyone that can explain to me what is happening when you run the code I really appreciate. I’ll paste the code I’m using

```
public class StarDiamond {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            for (int j = num; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int m = 1; m <= i; m++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int m = num; m >= i; m--) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Java SE 11 makes it possible to [do this kind of things in a succinct way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751028/10819573).

#### Explanation of the code in your question:

A nested loop (loop inside another loop) asks the system to run the inner loop (which may have one or more statements, conditions, further loops etc. inside its body) for each value of its enclosing loop. Let's consider the following example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

which outputs

```
*
**
***
```

The way it is processed is:

```
i = 1; if i <= 3   Yes  Execute the body
    j = 1; if j <= 1  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 2
    j = 2; if j <= 1  No  Terminate the inner loop
    Break the line and increment i to 2

i = 2; if i <= 3   Yes  Execute the body
    j = 1; if j <= 2  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 2
    j = 2; if j <= 2  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 3
    j = 3; if j <= 2  No  Terminate the inner loop
    Break the line and increment i to 3

i = 3; if i <= 3   Yes  Execute the body
    j = 1; if j <= 3  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 2
    j = 2; if j <= 3  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 3
    j = 3; if j <= 3  Yes  Execute the body
        Print "*" and increment j to 4
    j = 4; if j <= 3  No  Terminate the inner loop
    Break the line and increment i to 4

i = 4; if i <= 3   No  Terminate the outer loop
```

Comment: Really well explained answer